# Can't access hashmap in mapper, MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'd like to replace values of input data in my mapper, using dictionalies(csv) defined in another file. So I tried to put the csv data to HashMap and refer it in the mapper.

The java code and csv below are simplified version of my program. This code **works in my local environment**(Mac OS X, pseudo-distributed mode), but **doesn't in my EC2 instance(ubuntu, pseudo-distributed mode)**.

In detail, I got this stdout in process:

```
cat:4
human:2
flamingo:1
```

this means the filereader successfully put csv data into HashMap.

However the mapper mapped nothing and therefore I got empty output in the EC2 environment, although it mapped 3 * (the number of lines of the input file) elements and generated the following in the local:

```
test,cat
test,flamingo
test,human
```

Does anyone have answers or hints?

**Test.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInput; 
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordWriter;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableUtils;

public class Test {

  public static HashMap<String, Integer> map  = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

  public static class Mapper1 extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
    @Override
    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : map.entrySet()) {
        context.write(new Text(e.getKey()), new Text("test"));
      }
    }
  }

  public static class Reducer1 extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
    @Override
    protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> vals, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      context.write(new Text("test"), key);
    }
  }

  public static class CommaTextOutputFormat extends TextOutputFormat<Text, Text> {
    @Override
    public RecordWriter<Text, Text> getRecordWriter(TaskAttemptContext job) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      Configuration conf = job.getConfiguration();
      String extension = ".txt";
      Path file = getDefaultWorkFile(job, extension);
      FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(conf);
      FSDataOutputStream fileOut = fs.create(file, false);
      return new LineRecordWriter<Text, Text>(fileOut, ",");
    }
  }

  public static void get_list(String list_path){
    try {
      FileReader fr = new FileReader(list_path);
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
      String line = null, name = null;
      int leg = 0;

      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (!line.startsWith("name") && !line.trim().isEmpty()) {
          String[] name_leg = line.split(",", 0);
          name = name_leg[0];
          leg = Integer.parseInt(name_leg[1]);
          map.put(name, leg);
        }
      }
      br.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
      System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : map.entrySet()) {
      System.out.println(e.getKey() + ":" + e.getValue());
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    if (args.length != 3) {
      System.err.println(
        "Need 3 arguments: <input dir> <output base dir> <list path>");
      System.exit(1);
    }

    get_list(args[2]);
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "test");

    job.setJarByClass(Test.class);
    job.setMapperClass(Mapper1.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Reducer1.class);
    job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);

    // mapper output
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    // reducer output
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    // formtter
    job.setOutputFormatClass(CommaTextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    if(!job.waitForCompletion(true)){
      System.exit(1);
    }

    System.out.println("All Finished");
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

**list.csv (args[2])**

```
name,legs
cat,4
human,2
flamingo,1
```

#### =================================

I refer to @Rahul Sharma 's answer and modifiy my code as below. Then my code works in the both environments.

Thank you very much @Rahul Sharma and @Serhiy for your precise answer and useful comments.

**Test.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInput; 
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.net.URI;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordWriter;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableUtils;

public class Test {

  public static HashMap<String, Integer> map  = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

  public static class Mapper1 extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

    @Override
    protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      URI[] files = context.getCacheFiles();
      Path list_path = new Path(files[0]);

      try {
        FileSystem fs = list_path.getFileSystem(context.getConfiguration());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(list_path)));
        String line = null, name = null;
        int leg = 0;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
          if (!line.startsWith("name") && !line.trim().isEmpty()) {
            String[] name_leg = line.split(",", 0);
            name = name_leg[0];
            leg = Integer.parseInt(name_leg[1]);
            map.put(name, leg);
          }
        }
        br.close();
      }
      catch(IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }

      for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(e.getKey() + ":" + e.getValue());
      }
    }

    @Override
    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : map.entrySet()) {
        context.write(new Text(e.getKey()), new Text("test"));
      }
    }

  }

  public static class Reducer1 extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
    @Override
    protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> vals, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      context.write(new Text("test"), key);
    }
  }

  // Writer
  public static class CommaTextOutputFormat extends TextOutputFormat<Text, Text> {
    @Override
    public RecordWriter<Text, Text> getRecordWriter(TaskAttemptContext job) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      Configuration conf = job.getConfiguration();
      String extension = ".txt";
      Path file = getDefaultWorkFile(job, extension);
      FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(conf);
      FSDataOutputStream fileOut = fs.create(file, false);
      return new LineRecordWriter<Text, Text>(fileOut, ",");
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    if (args.length != 3) {
      System.err.println(
        "Need 3 arguments: <input dir> <output base dir> <list path>");
      System.exit(1);
    }

    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "test");
    job.addCacheFile(new Path(args[2]).toUri());

    job.setJarByClass(Test.class);
    job.setMapperClass(Mapper1.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Reducer1.class);
    job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);

    // mapper output
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    // reducer output
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    // formtter
    job.setOutputFormatClass(CommaTextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    if(!job.waitForCompletion(true)){
      System.exit(1);
    }

    System.out.println("All Finished");
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to learn more about mapreduce framework.

Your program behave as expected in local mode because Mapper, reducer and Job are launched on same JVM. In case, of pseudo-distributed mode or distributed modes there will be separate jvms allocated for each component. The values you put into hashMap using get_list are not visible to mapper and reducer as they are in  separate jvms

Use [distributed cache](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html) to make it work in cluster mode.

1. Job Main class add file to distributed cache:

   ```
   JobConf job = new JobConf();<br>
   DistributedCache.addCacheArchive(new URI(args[2]), job);
   ```
2. Access file in mapper or reducer:

   ```
   public void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

   Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
   FileSystem fs = FileSystem.getLocal(conf);

   Path[] dataFile = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(conf);
   BufferedReader cacheReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(dataFile[0])));
   // Implement here get_list method functionality

   }
   ```

Comment: I believe that OP told that even if ran on the local machine it is running in **pseudo-distributed mode** (thus I am not sure that you explanation for this particular case why it is running in local machine is valid). On another hand, you should never use local files, even with DistributedCache, since there is no guarantee that machine which submits the job will have the file, the solution is to move the file to the HDFS or HTTP server and access it remotely.

Comment: @Serhiy,> The way framework launch program in both modes is completely differetn. In local (standalone) each hadoop daemons run under same jvm as single process and in a pseudo-distributed mode(local system) each Hadoop daemon runs in a separate Java process. 2nd point: You can't add local files in distributed cache, first you have to place file in hdfs then add to Distributed cache from JobRunner.

Comment: Rahul Sharma and Serhiy > Thank you very much for your answer and comments. I found the difference in behavior comes from "dfs.replicate" settings. In my local environment "dfs.replication" in hdfs-site.xml is set to 1, so mapreduce works as a single-node mode. On the other hand,it is set to 3 in my EC2 instance. Anyway there's no good point in my code, I use DistributedCache.